# Flutter riverpod Change notifier not updating value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `riverpod` to manage states of some variables in my app like opacity, stroke width and color for my coloring app.

Here's my `opacity class` inside `notifier.dart`:

```
    class OpacityChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
      OpacityChangeNotifier([this.opacity = 1.0]);
      double opacity;
    
      void changeOpacity(double providedOpacity) {
        opacity = providedOpacity;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      void printOpacity() {
        print(opacity);
      }
    }
```

This is from my `OpacityPicker.dart`:

```
final _opacityProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<OpacityChangeNotifier>((ref) {
  return OpacityChangeNotifier();
});

class OpacityPicker extends ConsumerWidget {
  const OpacityPicker({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read(_opacityProvider).changeOpacity(0.1);
              context.read(_opacityProvider).printOpacity();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 20),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read(_opacityProvider).changeOpacity(0.5);
              context.read(_opacityProvider).printOpacity();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 30),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read(_opacityProvider).changeOpacity(1.0);
              context.read(_opacityProvider).printOpacity();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 40),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

finally this is my `menu_items.dart`:

```
final _opacityChangeProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<OpacityChangeNotifier>((ref) {
  return OpacityChangeNotifier();
});

class UtilityItems extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UtilityItems({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final opacityNotifier = watch(_opacityChangeProvider);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print(opacityNotifier.opacity);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.dock_rounded),
                )
              ],
            ),
            OpacityPicker(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine inside `OpacityPicker.dart`. When I'm pressing the opacity button the selected opacity is getting printed. But when I'm pressing the `Icons.dock_rounded` in `menu_items.dart` shouldn't I get the updated value?

It's showing the default value for opacity which is `1.0`

I've looked it up and all I got was some issues related to `changeNotifier` not working back in September 2020.

What am I missing here?

**N.B:** I've imported all the files correctly. And I want the value of opacity to change to the user selected one on pressed. So I need my `menu_item.dart` widget to know that.

Comment: You seem to be redefining the opacityProvider in both files. Is this correct? If so (without having any deeper knowledge) i would assume that the one notifier does not have any knowledge of the other notifier and thus will not get any update to the value.

Comment: @puelo Yes I did that. I need to set the initial opacity to 1.0 and the other two selectable values will be 0.1 and 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off @puelo comment, you shouldn't be redefining your ChangeNotifierProvider. The way you have it is two isolated providers with two separate ChangeNotifiers that have no knowledge of eachother.

I would recommend making `provider` a static member of your ChangeNotifier like so:

```dart
class OpacityChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  OpacityChangeNotifier([this.opacity = 1.0]);
  
  static final provider = ChangeNotifierProvider<OpacityChangeNotifier>((ref) {
    return OpacityChangeNotifier();
  });

  double opacity;
    
  void changeOpacity(double providedOpacity) {
    opacity = providedOpacity;
    notifyListeners();
  }
    
  void printOpacity() {
    print(opacity);
  }
}
```

To access:

```dart
context.read(OpacityChangeNotifier.provider);
```

This helps to keep your imports clean as well as avoiding redundant naming and reduces the likelihood someone else working on the project would end up creating another provider for that notifier.

Use that provider instead of defining it twice and that should solve your primary issue.

You should also always use `context.read` inside function handlers like `onPressed`. In your `menu_items.dart` you should refactor as follows:

```dart
class UtilityItems extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UtilityItems({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final opacity = context.read(OpacityChangeNotifier.provider).opacity;
                    print(opacity);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.dock_rounded),
                )
              ],
            ),
            OpacityPicker(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: got it. It all makes sense now tbh. Thanks